# replace string between html-tags, multiple occurances issue

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to replace a string by a regex in javascript but having problem to understand how the regex should be changed to match "**matchme** and **matchme**" only the first one is a match with the current regex.

```
var re = new RegExp("(<.+?>[^<>]*?)(" + searchString + ")([^<>]*?<.+?>)", "gi");
$(".contentdiv *:contains('" + searchString + "')").html(function (_, html) {
     return html.replace(re, '$1<span class="match">$2</span>$3');
});
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8wYlTx/2)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working for me, check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pnkzqfm4/)

My guess is this line:

```
$(".contentdiv *:contains('" + searchString + "')")
```

Is actually not returning the correct HTML element, **possibly**, that line of code is only getting the first tag where the `searchString` is.

Do:

```
console.log($(".contentdiv *:contains('" + searchString + "')"))
```

Is the correct element printed in the debug output?

If your problem presists, I would need more HTML code to understand the context and help you solve it.

**EDIT:**

Sorry I took so long... So, here is my proposed new RegExp:

```
/(create)([\sa-zA-Z0-9<])(?!.*\.\w+)/gi
```

Where you'll replace `create` by your `searchString`.

- 1st capture group is your search word;
- 2nd capture group is to accept any word followed by find spaces, letters, digits and tags starters;
- 3rd apture group is a negative lookahead to escape URLs that contain your search word (this is done by finding an extension);

Why didn't your RegExp worked? Because first captured the HTML tags, then **in the same capture group**, you captured whatever (.*?) until you found your word and then whatever again until you found the closing tags.

Well... that "whatever" could have your word repeated!

[New fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stp9nzdv/1/)

Comment: See the third row in the fiddle, only the first create is red.

Comment: `console.log($(".contentdiv *:contains('" + searchString + "')"));` does return all the elements But in the third examplerow the searchstring "create" occurs two times in the same element, thats is where the regex breaks.

Comment: Yup, I've realized your problem now, I'll probably suggest a new RegExp (I'm edditing the answer now)

Comment: Is your html going to be simillar to the example? I was trying to use a way simpler RegExp, but i don't know if it fits your requirements

Comment: Sorry for the time I took :P See new edit.

Comment: Looks good, I found some place where it was not working, see this fiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1hwe53xp/) Driving home from work now, will look closer into it when Im back home.

Comment: I saw your new fiddle. It works if you change the RegExp to /(create)([\sa-zA-Z0-9<\.])(?!.*\.\w+)/gi

Comment: But that's the thing, I'm adding a dot in the second capture group, so the second capture group catches whatever comes after your word. If you don't know all the possible cases, then you're probably looking for an HTML parser like suggested in the comments.